# Linking jquery-file into html

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio

I'm working in visual studio 2019. I made a folder called "wwwwroot". In that folder I have my jquery library that is called: "jquery-3.4.1.js", and I have the jquery-file that I want to use to do all my jquery stuff: "jquery-functions.js". When I open my run the code it appears and all, but my function that I have made in my jquery-file, doesn't work.

I've tried linking the jquery library with the google link too, to see if it affects my jquery-file somehow. But it obviously didn't work.

This would be my html-file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Testsite - Home</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="jquery-functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Mii</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And my jquery-file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").click(function () {
        $("p").hide();
    });

});
```

As you can see I want my p-tag to be hidden when I click on it, but that doesn't happen. It would be nice if someone could help me out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF0Qz.png)

Comment: No problem @GogoMagnus, I moved the comment to an answer.  Since this was a typo issue, I am going to vote to close (just wanted to give a heads up and a reason if you saw it).  Good luck with your learning!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a typo in your HTML markup (`src` is mispelled on your second script tag) which is preventing your functions file from even loading into the browser.

Update this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="jquery-functions.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-functions.js"></script>
```

And your library should load correctly.

Comment: We do have a specific close reason for typos, FYI...

Comment: I'm so sorry for wasting your time. Yes it was my misspelling thank you very much!

Comment: @HereticMonkey - yes we do, which I have invoked.  However, this is a very new user both to SO and web programming, so a bit of help will probably go a long way for Mr. Gogo

Comment: @Tommy Sure, I'm not saying, "Don't help him! Close close close!". A comment suffices. No need to make the question harder to delete by answering.